# Yammer API issue with thumbnail image

Tags: yammer

We are posting a message on yammer with og_image parameter set to a valid url that serves the image. But in the yammer user interface, message appears with a broken image. URL for an example image is "http://edubrite-com.edubrite.com/oltpublish/att/ae6e7132-8a2c-11e4-a3d9-00163e0054ca?t=l"

As you can see the url is valid but doesn't have a file like name at the end. Does the og_image needs to be ending with a file name?

We are using the API - https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to end with a file name, but it needs to be a file that is accessible over the internet because Yammer cannot authenticate as a custom user to access the image. When I go to that file it loads http://www.edubrite.com/oltpublish/site/cms.do which I assume is the result of the image requiring authentication.